# How do I use LibGDX, Gradle, Git, and Eclipse together?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gradle, libgdx

I have a LibGDX project for Android and Windows which I created with the LibGDX project setup app (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle), and I have no problems running the project on my main development computer. I want to work on this project from multiple computers and with other developers using Git, and so I placed all three projects into a Git repository. When I try downloading and importing the projects from the repository, I get a bunch of Build Path errors in 
Eclipse, since my main computer is a Mac and the other computers are Windows and Gradle downloaded the libraries for the projects to my User library (which I've always understood to be normal behavior). How do I fix this issue? Should my Git repository contain all the libraries, and then must I fix the build path by hand? If this is the case, what was the purpose of using Gradle in the first place?

Comment: Does all of the computers run a local project? Is the problem really on the git?

Comment: You don't, you install Android Studio and everything starts magically working automatically or by pressing a fix/download button. Glad I left Eclipse about a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have gradle integration with eclipse setup in all the computers, it will work if you do the following,

1. Do not commit any of eclipse metadata directories/files to the repo.
2. In the new computer (any OS) import(either after cloning externally or materializing from git) the gradle project and allow the tool chain to download dependencies and setup the eclipse project.

Comment: So would I only have the gradle files on the repository? None of the eclipse project files at all? And would Android work this way too?

Comment: Eclipse and Gradle are both project management tools. If your project is a gradle project all eclipse (with the gradle toolchain) needs is the gradle descriptor to create its own project structure.